# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un Jtree en un arrayList de forma jerárquica en java?

Tags: java

Este es mi código:

```
public class GeneradorDOM {   
public String tagRoot;

public ArrayList<GeneradorDOM> al_hijosDhijos;

public GeneradorDOM(String tagRoot) {
    this.tagRoot = tagRoot;
    al_hijosDhijos = new ArrayList<>();
 }
}
```

Ya he agregado el padre y los primeros hijos pero no se cómo agregarle los demás.
con este código lo hago pero solo los hijos de los primeros:

```
public void imprimirNodos(DefaultMutableTreeNode nodi, String selNode, String hijo2da) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodi.getRoot().getChildCount(); i++) {
        for (Enumeration nd = nodi.getRoot().getChildAt(i).children(); nd.hasMoreElements();) {
            if (nodi.getRoot().getChildAt(i).toString().equals("colors")) {

              //  System.out.println(nd.nextElement().toString());
                for (int j = 0; j < root.al_hijosDhijos.size(); j++) {
                    if (root.al_hijosDhijos.get(j).tagRoot.equals(selNode)) {
                        root.al_hijosDhijos.get(j).al_hijosDhijos.add(new GeneradorDOM(hijo2da));
                        //System.out.println("h2da:"+ hijo2da);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Me pueden ayudar a ingresar los demás hijos o con algún código mejor.

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu código, pero para los árboles generalmente se usan métodos recursivos.  El ejemplo que te voy a poner no necesariamente es para que resuelvas tu código, pero es para que veas como se puede iterar recursivamente un árbol.

Supongamos que tienes un nodo ráiz:

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode raiz; //supongamos que este es la raíz del árbol.
```

Vamos a usar este método para barrer todo el árbol:

```
public void barre(DefaultMutableTreeNode nodo) {
    if (nodo == null) {
      return;
    }
    Enumeration hijos = nodo.children();
    while (hijos.hasMorElements()) { ///por cada hijo del nodo que recibimos
       barre(hijos.nextElement());   ///lo vamos a barrer resursivamente
    }
}
```

Entonces podemos invocar :

```
barre(raiz);
```

Y debemos poder barrer todos los nodos de esa raíz con el método que te muestro. Ahora requieres agregar el código que te falte para que en esa barrida logres lo que deseas.